# Linux-based docker containers won’t run as expected on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, docker

If I run docker windows containers I can run docker commands ex:

```
docker ps
```

returns:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS   PORTS     NAMES
```

However if I switch to Linux containers (which is necessary for the image I need to build.) via docker desktop on Windows and try same command

```
docker ps
```

It returns:

```
error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried:

- switching the docker daemon to Windows (this fails to solve my problem given I need the linux daemon running as previously stated.)
- clicking the "Reset to factory defaults" button in docker desktop
- activating the "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" option in docker desktop
- signing out and then back into my docker account
- quitting docker desktop via the system tray, shutting down wsl with 'wsl --shutdown' and then re-opening docker desktop (in that order).
- uninstalling/reinstalling docker desktop
- uninstalling/reinstalling the ubuntu 18.04 server on my PC.

Additional info:
the message appearing on the main display when I open docker desktop reads: "Docker Desktop failed to stop..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the issue after unregistering the docker-desktop-data distro which is used by the docker-desktop distro as the backing store for container images etc. as well unregistering the docker-desktop distro.

running following commands in Powershell as admin fixed the issue:

- `wsl --unregister docker-desktop`
- `wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data`

Comment: Great self-solved question!